# Multi-step form, next step button won't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

### "Continue" to next step of the form won't work.

> onclick event for button:

`<button onclick="processPhase1()">Continue</button>`

> Function:

```
function processPhase1() {
    ("phase1").style.display = "none";
    ("phase2").style.display = "block";
}
```

> Example form (to display my structure):

```
<form>
    <div id="phase1">
        <!-- Some Input field -->
        <!-- Some Input field -->
            <button onclick="processPhase1()">Next Step</button>
    </div>
    <div id="phase2">
        <!-- Some Input field -->
        <!-- Some Input field -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Of course, the 2nd phase isn't displayed when I'm trying to go to next step, since I've the suitable css for it. The problem is, it wont go to next step.

*If you want to take a look in my code just let me know.*

**EDIT:** Sorry not to mention it earlier. I'm using

```
function _(x) {
                return document.getElementById(x);  
              }
```

and then putting _ infront of the ("phase1"),("phase2") but it still won't work

### Part of my code: [Click Here.](http://pastie.org/10493319)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of "_" as a stand-in for getElementById seems to needlessly risk conflict (or at least confusion) with the underscore library, but it does work:

```js
function _(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
  }

function processPhase1() {
    _("phase1").style.display = "none";
    _("phase2").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div id="phase1">
      This is phase 1
            <button onclick="processPhase1()">Next Step</button>
    </div>
    <div id="phase2" style="display:none">
      This is phase 2
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for taking a look, although this didn't help me understand/resolve my issue. If it did work, I wouldn't be posting a question in the first place

Comment: I understand that something isn't working.  The purpose of this answer is to  demonstrate that whatever your problem is, it isn't with the code you've presented in the question. Because it does work here, as you can see.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you somehow, didn't mean to. Here's my code if you have some time to take a look at http://pastie.org/10493319

Comment: I'm not offended, I'm pointing out that your reduced test case has eliminated the bug, which indicates that the bug is elsewhere.   I don't see any immediately obvious problems with the code in your pastie, but the first things I'd try is watching the console for error messages, checking to ensure that you don't have conflicts with other code not shown here, adding console.logs to confirm that your processPhase functions are actually getting called, etc.  "It still won't work" doesn't give you or us enough information to go on.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. I will try everything you suggested and come back with more details

Comment: When I replaced _ with la for function name. It worked. Thank you Daniel for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

If the `button` is inside a form (unknown based on your code), and the `type` of the button is not specified (as above), it will default to `submit` and submit that form. It's possible your page is just reloading on the form submission.

The simplest fix is to `return false;` after processing the click:

```
<button onclick="processPhase1(); return false;">Next Step</button>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I've included return false but the result is the same. Nothing happens, as it's not even clicked, although I used console.log('test') and it returns test, in the console ofc.